# Como agregar campos a formulario Registrarse en web odoo 12?

Tags: xml, odoo, xpath

La vista que quiero modificar esta en:

```
odoo/addons/auth_signup/views/auth_signup_login_templates.xml
```

Necesito modificar el template donde aparecen los div de correo, nombre, contraseña. Seria el siguiente que esta ubicado en la dirección antes mencionada:

```
<template id="auth_signup.fields" name="Auth Signup/ResetPassword form fields">

            <div class="form-group field-name">
                <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" t-att-value="name" id="name" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="e.g. John Doe"
                    required="required" t-att-readonly="'readonly' if only_passwords else None"
                    t-att-autofocus="'autofocus' if login and not only_passwords else None" />
            </div>
</template>
```

Quiero agregar otro Div, para meter otra información con un archivo xml en mi propio modulo , lo estoy haciendo asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="sign" inherit_id="auth_signup.fields" name="sign Inherit">
        <xpath expr="//div[class='form-group field-name']" position="after">
            <div><h1>este es un nuevo campo</h1></div>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

La terminal me esta arrojando el error de que no lo encuentra en el padre:

```
El elemento '<xpath expr="//div[class='form-group field-name']">' no puede ser localizado en la vista padre
```

Si me ayudan que error estoy cometiendo , Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

cambie esta linea de busqueda en el xpath y funciono correctamente

```
<xpath expr="//div[4]" position="after">
```

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/201318)

Comment: Mi respuesta es correcta, no veo el motivo de tu molestia.